# django 'set' object has no attribute 'items' error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to deploy my django app on AWS. I create a web-crawler inside my app using bs4 adn requests.I used that to get data from e-commerce sites.it's works perfectly on amazon but it throw this(see at image1) when I try to scrape from newegg. but the same codes works on localhost. first I thought it's the user agent issue and I tried with other user agent but didn't works.

I really can't figure out whats the issue so if you know what cause this error then please tell it will be very helpfull.

the code and image below:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92LPi.png)

```
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"}
url = "https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d="+query
data = re.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'lxml')

items_container = soup.find("div", {"class":"list-wrap"})
items = items_container.find("div", {"class":"items-view"})

prdList = []
for item in items.find_all("div", {"class":"item-container"}):
    header = item.find("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    title = header.text
    link = header["href"]

    img = item.find("a", {"class":"item-img"})
    imgsrc = img.find("img")["src"]           

    price = item.find("li", {"class":"price-current"})
    if price == None:
        price = '$--'
    else:
        price = price.find("strong").text    

    prdList.append(Scraper.prdTmplt(imgsrc, title, price, link, site))

allProduct = prdList
return allProduct
```

The Error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://ec2-54-179-183-56.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/search?sq=gaming+laptop&site_selected=newegg&sq-submit=Search

Django Version: 2.2.6
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['groups.apps.GroupsConfig',
 'product_details.apps.ProductDetailsConfig',
 'scraper.apps.ScraperConfig',
 'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/ubuntu/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/ubuntu/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ubuntu/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/best-price-py/pages/views.py" in search
  29.             context['bb'] = Scraper.neweggList(search_query, site)

File "/home/ubuntu/best-price-py/scraper/scrapers.py" in neweggList
  120.         data = re.get(url)

File "/home/ubuntu/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py" in get
  75.     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py" in request
  60.         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in request
  519.         prep = self.prepare_request(req)

File "/home/ubuntu/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in prepare_request
  462.             hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),

File "/home/ubuntu/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py" in prepare
  314.         self.prepare_headers(headers)

File "/home/ubuntu/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py" in prepare_headers
  446.             for header in headers.items():

Exception Type: AttributeError at /search
Exception Value: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of your error. Click the link that says "Switch to copy-and-paste view" and post the resulting text in the question.

Comment: updated to question see now

Comment: Show the `neweggList` method in your scrapers.py.

Comment: it;s the code above the error

Comment: stacktrace mentions `data = re.get(url)`, but the code contains `header` parameter as well - `data = re.get(url,headers=headers)`. Either the code or the error you posted are outdated

Answer (score 0):

the headers dict you passed are is rendered as a set  and not as a dictionary. Look at the dump in the image.